# c++ token Impersonation to modify HKEY_CURRENT_USERS from service

Tags: c++, windows, session, token

I am running a service (in local account). I have used `WTSEnumerateSessions`to retrive all the current sessionID. Then i found impersonation token and usertoken with the help of `WTSQueryUserToken` and `GetTokenInformation`. I have called the method `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` , after performing tasks I called 'revertToSelf'

For the first session it works very fine( from SYSTEM account to userAccount). But for the next session, i am still accessing the previous user HKEY_CURRENT_USERS
(When I retrieve account name is works perfectly). But when i try to update the HKEY_CURRENT_USER, it will add the changes to the previous session ( I have called revertoself before start working with next session

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Impersonation changes the result of security checks, it does not change the view of the registry, in this case the per-user keys.

To update HKEY_CURRENT_USER for a particular user, you need to look in HKEY_USERS and locate the key belonging to the user whose registry you wish to modify.

They key names will look something like this:

- HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-123412341-123412341-123412341-1061
- HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-123412341-123412341-123412341-1061_Classes

The S-1-5 part is the string representation of the user's SID, which you obtain from `OpenThreadToken`, `GetTokenInformation` and convert with `ConvertSidToStringSid`

Comment: Thanks your reply. Currently i have session Id. How to get SID from session id?

Comment: After impersonating, use OpenThreadToken, GetTokenInformation.

Comment: In `OpethreadToken` , I have passed Get `GetCurrentThread()` as Handle.Then I called `GetTokenInformation()`with `TokenLogonSid` as a parameter. But I have recieving some random SID ( not the acutal SID) ( I have converted sidtoString. But still i am not able to retrieve exact sid of the loggedon user

Comment: I getting smaller SID like group SID . But the one present in the HKEY_USERS is long . so how do i get that logon SID

Comment: The smaller SID is probably a Well-Known-SID. That means you haven't impersonated a user, it is probably SYSTEM or something.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

Comment: Psychic debugging: Your impersonation failed. Did you check the return value?

Comment: I have checked the return type and I have called `GetUserName` to verify the impersonation. The trick worked for is I have used HKEY returned from `RegOpenCurrentUser` rather than `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

Comment: @gajapathyp you should put that as an answer. It is allowed to answer your own questions. :-)

Comment: @gajapathyp I think you need `TokenUser` with `GetTokenInformation()`. That said, RegOpenCurrentUser is probably better for your purposes.